# Application built on Windows Server 2012 R2 fails on windows server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, c++, mfc, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

I have MFC application built on windows server 2012 R2. It works fine on non-build machines Windows Server 2012 R2. But It fails to start on Windows Sevrer 2008 R2.

Both machines are 64bit. Some more information about the MFC application.
My app has both managed and unmanaged code.I have one dll which has support for common language runtime CLR. I load it on runtime. My application is targeted for .NetFramework4.0

I have installed both .netframework4.0 and .netframework4.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. Still it fails to start the application.

Comment: Have you installed C++ and/or MFC redistributable packages as well?

Comment: Yes. I have installed redestributable packages.

Comment: Please define "it fails to start". Does it display an error message?

Comment: do you hard link to any api-ms-win-core dlls? do not take a direct dependency on those dlls. use the dlls documented in windows 7 sdk instead.

Comment: Michael Walz : Yes it give 0xc000007b error code.

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 : I don't have any direct references to api-ms-win-core-dlls. But Some of my 3rd party libs have dependency on api-ms-win-core-dll.

Comment: The issue is resolved and it was solved by adding dynamic linking of boost libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application which was built on Windows Server 2012 R2 and it was statically linked with Boost Library.

The scenario was like this, I had both managed and native built libraries. When I referred a C++\CLI library which was statically linked to Boost libraries was failing to load with the linker.

**Solution:** Link boost libraries dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

One of the common trouble shooting tool is to look at the `Event Viewer` to see whether it has logged any exceptions.

It is likely that there are missing dependencies for your unmanaged DLL. One common tool to check this is the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: There are no logs in event viewer. And I tried dependency walker, adding dlls didn't help much.